# Using DispositionNotification with Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3

I am working with a set of specialized email servers that are configured to return Message Disposition Notifications (MDNs) upon successful receipt of the message.  I have developed a Javamail client that is used to send messages to one of these servers and retrieve returned MDNs from the user's POP3 INBOX folder.

How do I go about getting at the disposition notification body part from the returned MimeMessage I retrieve from the user's inbox?  I've found the com.sun.mail.dsn.DispositionNotification class but haven't seen an example of how to correctly create an instance of a DispositionNotification using the constructor:

```
DispositionNotification(InputStream)
```

Should I be able get the InputStream from  a MimeMessage and use it to create the DispositionNotification, like so?

```
Message[] msgs = getInboxMessages();    
DispositionNotification dn = new DispositionNotification(msgs[0].getInputStream();
```

Or is there some other way this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getContent method on such a message should return a MultipartReport object (a special subclass of the usual MimeMultipart object), from which you can access the parts of the report.  The MultipartReport.getReport() method will return either a DeliveryStatus or DispositionNotification object, depending on the type of the report.

Comment: @Bill_Shannon This was very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: MultipartReport report = (MultipartReport) msgs[i].getContent();
    if (msgs[i].getContentType().contains("disposition-notification")) {
        DispositionNotification dn = (DispositionNotification) report.getReport();
        InternetHeaders inetHeaders = dn.getNotifications();
        Enumeration headers = inetHeaders.getAllHeaders();
        String msgId = inetHeaders.getHeader("Original-Message-ID", ";");
        String disp = inetHeaders.getHeader("Disposition", ";");
    }